# Yii Cgridview

Tags: activerecord, yii

Есть почти стандартный CRUD и экшн admin, который через CGridView выводит все записи из таблицы. Так вот в таблице есть три статуса, два из которых (0 и 1) пользователь может менять и сортировать по ним, а статус 2 - чисто технический и если какая-то запись в таблице имеет этот статус, то она не должна попадать в этот вот список строк в CGridView.
Подскажите, как лучше сделать такую вот штуку? Подозреваю,ч то нужно все решить в контроллере, но вопрос как?

UPD: вьюха

```
 <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
                'id'           => 'news-grid',
                'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
                'filter'=>$model1,
                'itemsCssClass' => 'table table-bordered items',
                'summaryText' => '',
                'pager'=>array(
                    'class'=>'CLinkPager',

                ),

                'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'grid-view2'),
                'columns'=>array(
                    array(
                        'header' => '№',
                        'value' => '$row+1',
                    ),

                    array('name'=>'title',
                    'type'=>'raw',
                    'filter'=>CHtml::activeTextField($model, 'title',array("placeholder"=>"Поиск...")),

                    ),

                    array(
                        'name'=>'date',
                        'type'=>'date',
                        'filter' => ''

                    ),
                    array('name'=>'text',
                          'type'=>'raw',
                          'filter'=>CHtml::activeTextField($model, 'text',array("placeholder"=>"Поиск...")),

                    ),
                    array(
                        'name'=>'status',
                        'type'=>'raw',
                        'filter' => array(0=>'Активен', 1=> 'В архиве'),
                        'value'=>'  $data->status==0 ? "Активен" : "В архиве"',
                        'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'100px'),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
                        'updateButtonUrl'=>'CHtml::normalizeUrl(array("update","id"=>$data->id, ))',
                        'viewButtonImageUrl'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/view.png',
                        'updateButtonImageUrl'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/update.png',
                        'deleteButtonImageUrl'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/delete.png',
                    ),
                ),
            )); ?>
```

Версия:  1.1.14
По поводу $model и $model1 станет ясно из кода контроллера.

```
public function actionAdmin()
    {

        $model=new Auction('search');

        $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        $model1=Auction::model()->findAll('status<>:status', array(':status'=>2));

        if(isset($_GET['Auction']))
            $model->attributes=$_GET['Auction'];

        $this->render('admin',array(
            'model'=>$model, 'model1'=>$model1
        ));
    }
```

Comment: YII версия какая? а код контролера? и вот 'dataProvider'=>$model->search(), 'filter'=>$model1, что есть что поподробнее?

Comment: Так что? Никто не в курсе как можно решить данный вопрос?

Comment: Важно: Если вдруг кому-нибудь это понадобится. Если Вам по какой-то причине не нужно выводить определенные записи из Вашей таблицы в грид, то проще всего указать это в самой модели в методе search(). У меня это дополнение выглядит так:  $criteria->condition = 'status <>2';

Comment: тогда уж делай scoup в модели - читай тутhttp://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/ru/database.ar в  Именованные группы условий . А лучше прочитай полностью документацию, смотри исходники - они кстати очень понятны

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте при выборке списка фильтр status <>2

```
$user=User::model()->findAll('status<>:status', array(':status'=>2));
```

я так понимаю вы новичек в данной области. Ладно - читаем вот неплохую статейку по виджету [zii.widgets.grid.CGridView](http://progergirl.blogspot.ru/2012/05/cgridview_27.html)
Кстати ВОПРОС - у вас поле status реально есть в таблице Auction?

Из нее сейчас необходимо уяснить следующее :

1. для чего нужно свойство dataProvider. Что в него нада передавать.
2. для чего нужно свойство filter. Что в него нада передавать.

Анализируем код вашего контроллера.
в  $model - содержится модель Auction, с введенными пользователем  полями (свойствами) - следовательно - это должно быть использовано для свойства filter виджеда zii.widgets.grid.CGridView . Смотрим вашу вьюху -> $model вы передали в свойство dataProvider.- ИСПРАВЛЯЕМ.

Согласно документации в dataProvider лучше передавать экземпляр CActiveDataProvider, так давайте это и сделаем - плюс к этому добавим что нам нада выбрать статус не равный 2.

```
public function actionAdmin()
    {
//создадим фильтр на основе введенных юзером данных
        $filter=new Auction();
        $filter->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
        if(isset($_GET['Auction']))
            $filter->attributes=$_GET['Auction'];

//создадим экземпляр класса CActiveDataProvider для нашей модели Auction
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Auction', array(
        'criteria'=>array(
              'condition'=>'status<>2'),
        ));

        $this->render('admin',array(
            'dataprovider'=>$dataProvider, 'filter'=>$filter
        ));
    }
```

небольшие исправления во вьюхе

```
 <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
                'id'           => 'news-grid',
                'dataProvider'=>$dataprovider,
                'filter'=>$filter,
//далее везде заменяем $model на $filter
```

Теперь вопрос вам  $model->attributes=$_GET['Auction'] - вы смысл понимаете что тут происходит? и почему у вас может модель не заполнятся данными от юзера , хотя они приходят?

Comment: Извините, а можно пример?

Comment: Я так понял это в контроллере надо использовать в actionAdmin(). Если да, то в рендер надо отдать вместо $model=new User('search'); вот это? 
$model=User::model()->findAll('status<>:status', array(':status'=>2));
Если да, то это не работает (выводится половина html, который идет до вывода грида). Ошибок не выводится.

Comment: тогда поподробнее что выводите - вьюхи приведи код

Comment: Спасибо большое! Все очень хорошо расписано и понятно. Status действительно есть в таблице Auction. По поводу  $model->attributes=$_GET['Auction'] не совсем понимаю. По идее у Вас вместо $model->attributes... должно стоять $filter->attributes... И в condition 'status<>2'. Тогда все работает, но перестал работать поиск... Поиск изменил на  
array('name'=>'title',
                    'type'=>'raw',
                    'filter'=>CHtml::activeTextField($filter, 'title',array("placeholder"=>"Поиск...")),

                    ),

Comment: точно вместо $model нада  $filter) щас поправлю и по статусу тож - с утра с день рождения был )))

Comment: по поводу понимания  $model->attributes=$_GET['Auction']  - читаем вот  тут http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/ru/form.model